# How to read configuration parameters for custom Deployer module?

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

I have a custom deployer extension and a configuration file with some of the parameters required for the extension. The custom extension checks if the component exists in a table in the database, if not, it is inserted, if yes then the LastUpdate date is changed.

This is what the `cd_deployer_conf.xml` file looks like:

```
<Processor Action="Deploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor">
<Module Class="com.SomeClass.tridion.deployer.CacheFlusher" Type="CacheFlusher">
    <ServerName>SomeServer</ServerName>
    <DataBaseName>SomeDB</DataBaseName>
    <UserName>SomeUser</UserName>
    <Password>Password</Password>
</Module>
```

In the java class, the code to get these parameters & establish the connection to the database  is :

```
String strServerName = config.getAttribute("ServerName");
String strDataBaseName = config.getAttribute("DataBaseName");
String strUserName = config.getAttribute("UserName");
String strPassword = config.getAttribute("Password");

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection cnnConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s;databaseName=%s", strServerName, strDataBaseName),
    strUserName,
    strPassword
);
```

However, whenever I deploy, this is the error that I get in the logs.

> ERROR CacheFlusher - com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: No attribute found for: ServerName.

What am I doing wrong ?

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you add some more info? I.e. which class/interface is your module extending/implementing? Which method are you implementing? What is object `config`?

Comment: Thanks Mihai,
 
Config object is configuration
public CacheFlusher(Configuration config, Processor processor) throws ConfigurationException {
  super(config, processor);
 }

We are trying to extend.
public void process(TransportPackage data) throws ProcessingException {
Did I answer your questions correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Configuration object is context sensitive. This means it represents a certain node in your configuration file. AFAIK, the default node is the `Module` node itself. So you have to read a child node (e.g. `ServerName`) and then read some of its attributes.

You will need to use the following methods:

- `Configuration.getChild()`
- `Configuration.getAttribute()`

I suggest to rewrite the configuration XML to the following:

```
<Module Class="com.SomeClass.tridion.deployer.CacheFlusher" Type="CacheFlusher">
    <ServerName Value="SomeServer" />
    <DataBaseName Value="SomeDB" />
    <UserName Value="SomeUser" />
    <Password Value="Password" />
</Module>
```

then some sample code would be:

```
Configuration serverConfig = config.getChild("ServerName");
String serverName = serverConfig.getAttribute("Value");
```

For completeness you could also check for the existence of certain nodes/attribtues using methods:

- `Configuration.hasChild()`
- `Configuration.hasAttribute()`

Comment: Thanks for the solution Mihai! You are awesome! My log file is now error free after I made all the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
<ServerName>SomeServer</ServerName>
<DataBaseName>SomeDB</DataBaseName>
<UserName>SomeUser</UserName>
<Password>Password</Password>
```

Try this to specify your custom parameters:

```
<Properties>
    <Property Name="ServerName" Value="SomeServer" />
    <Property Name="DataBaseName" Value="SomeDB" />
    <Property Name="UserName" Value="SomeUser" />
    <Property Name="Password" Value="Password" />
</Properties>
```

Comment: Thanks Nickoli. I still get the same errors after I made these config changes and restarted the deployer website.